# How to get Time span values(Format HH:mm:ss) from the Kendo Timepicker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, timepicker

I am setting a time picker using the Kendo time picker, which displays in the format "HH:mm:ss" but not binding properly, shows the Date along with it.
Please Check this link.
Example usage of Kendo UI for Angular
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/timepicker/formats/

I tried with pipes too (with this link https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-tips-formatting-dates-with-a-custom-date-pipe-dd-mm-yyyy/ ). But that too not working. Please help me.

```
 <div class="example-wrapper" style="min-height: 400px;">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 example-col">
              <p>Select a long time: {{value}}</p> // Problem Here 
              <kendo-timepicker
                  [format]="'HH:mm:ss'"
                  [value]="value"
              ></kendo-timepicker>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 example-col">
              <p>Select a short time:</p>
              <kendo-timepicker
                  [format]="'hh:mm a'"
                  [value]="value"
              ></kendo-timepicker>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Expected Result : 00:00:00(timestamps) to bound near {{value}}, which is to be used in the forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link 2 is working , by removing the ${Constants.DATE_FMT} thus

```
static readonly DATE_TIME_FMT = `${Constants.DATE_FMT} hh:mm:ss`;
```

becomes

```
static readonly DATE_TIME_FMT = `hh:mm:ss`;
```